# Flex: Restrict data input

Tags: apache-flex, validation

I have a TextField as:

```
 <s:TextInput restrict="A-Z0-9_" maxChars="30"/>
```

And I am restricting the input to:

> - Capital letters
> - Numbers
> - _
> - no spaces
> - max chars 30

How can I restrict the input more to allow only letters at the begging and end?

Comment: The examples section in the @hering's answer contain sample code. The regex you're looking for is `^[A-Z]([A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z])?$`

Comment: Thanx @Amarghosh I was hopping that I could do it with the range. But regex it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restrict-field validates immediately when the user types in something.
You need an [RegExp-Validator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/RegExpValidator.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) to validate after the user wants to submit the data, so you can't use the restrict-field.